# Combining degree and \textsubscript

Tags: amsmath, textcomp

Is it possible to combine `\textsubscript` and the `\degree` fonction from `gensymb` to get the subscript perfectly underneath the degree sign ?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\newcommand\tind[1]{{\textsubscript{#1}}}
\newcommand\texp[1]{{\textsuperscript{#1}}}
\def\tixp#1#2{\rlap{\textsuperscript{#1}}\textsubscript{#2}}

\begin{document}
90\degree\tind{+x} doesn't give quite the same result as 90\tixp{$\circ$}{x}.
\end{document}
```

With the font I use in my main document ([DejaVu TT](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page)), I get the following result when using `\degree`

[image]

and `$^\circ$`

[image]

As you can see, the degree is slightly shifted down when using `$^\circ$`. I can, of course, take any solution that does not require `gensymb`.

Comment: Not sure why you don't do `$90\degree_{+x}$`

Comment: is there a reason that `90\tixp{$\circ$}{+x}` wouldn't be acceptable?

Comment: @egreg `$90\degree_{+x}$` does not give +x and the degree sign aligned.
@barbarabeeton see edited post. Sorry, I went too fast and assumed you would get the same shift with the default font.

Comment: @HcN That's because `\degree` is badly defined.

Comment: @egreg It there an alternative ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\rlap` around `\degree`.  Then the subscript will basically ignore the degree, and they will be on top of each other:

```
90\rlap{\degree}\tind{x}
```

Of course, the degree sign is not centered above the x, but both are aligned right next to the number 90.

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. Both number shifted left. Thanks a lot indeed. I made it a function `\newcommand{\degrl}[1]{\rlap{\degree}\textsubscript{#1}}`